# CSS grid different number of columns

Tags: css, sass

[image: Grid example]

[image]

I want to make a grid with different column sizes ('ITEM = V' covers all width 'ITEM A' or 'P' or 'T' cover each 50 percent of the grid width), as shown in the image. Any help?

i ve been tryin to solve this for a week now. Really what's wrong with this. (video should take two columns)

```
<div  class="grid-container">
    <div *ngFor="let media of allMedia">
      <div *ngIf="media.type==='V'" class="item1">
        {{media.title}}
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="media.type==='A'" >
         {{media.title}}
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="media.type==='P'" >**Bold Text Here**
        {{media.title}}
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="media.type==='T'">
        {{media.title}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
   .grid-container {
     display: grid;
     background-color: #2196F3;
     grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  }


  .item1 {
     grid-area:  2 / 1 /  span  2 / span 2 !important;
    border-style:solid;
    text-align:center
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

It'd be best to use `display: grid;` for something like this.

You'd have to add unique classes/id's for the children elements and then set the `grid-area` property on each of them.

The layout of `grid-area` is:

```
grid-area: row-start / column-start / row-end / column end;
```

You can also use shorthand if two properties have the same value:

```
grid-area: 2 / 1
/* Equates to: */
grid-area: 2 / 1 / 2 / 1
```

Example:

```css
.outer-grid {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
}

.newspaper1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 3 / 2 / 1;
  border-style: solid;
}

.newspaper2 {
  grid-area: 2 / 1;
  border-style: solid;
}

.newspaper3 {
  grid-area: 2;
  border-style: solid;
}

.newspaper4 {
  grid-area: 3 / 1;
  border-style: solid;
}

.newspaper5 {
  grid-area: 3 / 2;
  border-style: solid;
}

.newspaper6 {
  grid-area: 4 / 3 / 4 / 1;
  border-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-grid">
  <div *ngIf="item==='V'" class="newspaper1">
    some content
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="item==='A'" class="newspaper2">
    some content
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="item==='P'" class="newspaper3">
    some content
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="item==='T'" class="newspaper4">
    some content
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="item==='A'" class="newspaper5">
    some content
  </div>
    <div *ngIf="item==='V'" class="newspaper6">
    some content
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a good interface for learning CSS Grid if you want to learn more: https://alialaa.github.io/css-grid-cheat-sheet/

Comment: Thanks Daniel but there are more than 6 results and the order, i havent define them

Comment: i think the problem is that the results could be more of one for video so you can specify the row the video is going to be